# sort files on the filesystem using a cutom sort

Tags: python-3.x

I have a directory containing files like

```
file23.txt
file2.txt etc,
```

I want the output to be

```
file2.txt
file23.txt
```

any ideas ?

I have tried this

```
files = os.listdir(r'D:\Test\thread\xml')

sorted(files)
```

I want to use a lambda to the sorted function that takes my lambda as key and sorts it.

Comment: What trouble have you had with the task so far?

Comment: Rob sorry i forgot to post what i have tried let me to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for listing files in `mydir` and sorting by name?

```
import os
print(sorted(os.listdir('mydir/')))
```

If you are sorting by the digit in them, you might try

```
import os
import re

def sorter(filename):
    match = re.search(r'\d+', filename)
    if match:
        return int(match.group())
    return 0

files = sorted(os.listdir('mydir/'), key = lambda fname: sorter(fname))
```

This will put all filenames with no digits in them at the front of the list.